# Запрет ввода символов в Linux консоле на C++

Tags: c++, linux

как можно запретить ввод букв внутри терминала? Жмем клавишу, программа сразу отрабатывает, понимает, что это буква и ничего не происходит. Жмем на цифру, появляется в строке ввода цифра.

Comment: Отключить echo;  дополнительно, скорее всего, надо перейти в raw (или cbreak) режим ввода. Подробнее https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr

Answer (score 0):

Придумал только так... Выглядит страшно, но работает так как хотел. Есть ошибка когда число слишком большое.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int RotateNumber(int number) {
   std::ostringstream output_stream;
   int result;
   output_stream << number;
   std::string str_number = output_stream.str();
   std::reverse(str_number.begin(),str_number.end());
   std::istringstream input_stream(str_number, std::istringstream::in);
   input_stream >> result;
   return result;
}
int main()
{
   char c;
   int temp;
   int tempp = 1;
   int end = 0;
   struct termios tty, savetty;
while (true){
   fflush(stdout);
   tcgetattr(0, &tty);
   savetty = tty;
   tty.c_lflag &= ~(ISIG | ICANON);
   tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
   tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &tty);
   read(0, &c, 1);
   tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &savetty);
   if ( c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9')
   {
        temp = c - '0';
        end += temp * tempp;
        tempp *= 10;
   }
   else
   {
        system("clear");
        cout << RotateNumber(end);
   }
}
   return 0;
}
```